# Clipping node to camera for only one axis

Tags: swift, scenekit

I would like to have a `node` in the `scene`, that is somehow clipped to `camera node` only for `y` axis. So that when camera moves, this node stays at the same `y` but moves in `x` and `z` with the rest of the scene. Is there some special way I could do something like this, or is the only way to movie the node every time camera moves?

Comment: You want to add the node as a child of the camera node. Then when you move the camera node, you can also move the child node on the x and z axis. The only problem with this is that you can only move the camera on the x and z axis as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`SCNTransformConstraint`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scntransformconstraint) to have a blocked called at every frame that takes the node's transform and returns a new transform that satisfies your criteria.

There are conversion utils such as [`convertPosition:toNode:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1407990-convertposition) that will allow you to have the node's position in the coordinate system of the camera, and then back to coordinate system of the node's parent after you modified the `y` coordinate. Just remember to use the [presentation nodes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1408030-presentationnode) if there are animations, actions or physics in your scene.